# Validating unknown key and values

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

In XSD I am trying to validate - if the key matches a certain value then I want to validate if the property is correct from several strings.

I am not sure if it is possible,and if it is I don't know how.

```
 <xs:element name="property" type="tpmProperty"/>

<xs:complexType name="tpmProperty">
  <xs:sequence/>
  <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

and I have these rules and many more ,for example :

```
    <property key="postProcessingMode" value="(none, script, java class)" />
    <property key="flagFileApplicability" value="(file, directory)" />
     <property key="flag" value="..." />
```

the brackets mean what possible value can be there for example

```
  <property key="postProcessingMode" value="script" />
```

is valid and

```
  <property key="postProcessingMode" value="123" />
```

is NOT valid

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of "cross-validation" like this you need XSD 1.1, which provides two ways of doing it: assertions, and conditional type attribution. XSD 1.1 is implemented in Altova, Saxon, and Xerces, but many of the older schema processors like the one from Microsoft don't provide it.